# symfony2: ContextErrorException on production server "Erroneous data format for unserializing"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, production-environment

I want to deploy symfony2 application. On localhost works perfect, the only difference my web directory is in public_html, but when I installed on my prod server, after register some user, the exception has been thrown. Looks like unserializing can't decode, my entity "0:{}":

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'CodeCats\PanelBundle\Entity\User' in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 869

    in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 869
    at ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'Erroneous data format for unserializing 'CodeCats\PanelBundle\Entity\User'', '/home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php', '869', array())
    at unserialize('O:32:"CodeCats\PanelBundle\Entity\User":0:{}') in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 869
    at ClassMetadataInfo->newInstance() in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2444
    at UnitOfWork->newInstance(object(ClassMetadata)) in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2546
    at UnitOfWork->createEntity('CodeCats\PanelBundle\Entity\User', array('id' => '1', 'username' => 'tomek11', 'email' => 'tomek11@gmail.com', 'password' => '2f5e325c351294588e238389d1cc86a39a0c58f2', 'grade' => 'USER', 'avatar_id' => null, 'companyEmail_id' => null), array()) in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php line 132
    at SimpleObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData(array('id1' => '1', 'username2' => 'tomek11', 'email3' => 'tomek11@gmail.com', 'password4' => '2f5e325c351294588e238389d1cc86a39a0c58f2', 'grade5' => 'USER', 'avatar_id6' => null, 'companyEmail_id7' => null), array('id1' => array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'integer'), 'username2' => array('name' => 'username', 'type' => 'string'), 'email3' => array('name' => 'email', 'type' => 'string'), 'password4' => array('name' => 'password', 'type' => 'string'), 'grade5' => array('name' => 'grade', 'type' => 'string'), 'avatar_id6' => array('name' => 'avatar_id', 'type' => 'integer'), 'companyEmail_id7' => array('name' => 'companyEmail_id', 'type' => 'integer')), array()) in /home/progress/domains/progress-checker.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php line 48
```

Additional info: The magic gpc in turned on.

**Update**
my check.php result:

```
** Mandatory requirements **

 OK       PHP version must be at least 5.3.3 (5.4.29 installed)
 OK       PHP version must not be 5.3.16 as Symfony won't work properly with it
 OK       Vendor libraries must be installed
 OK       app/cache/ directory must be writable
 OK       app/logs/ directory must be writable
 OK       date.timezone setting must be set
 OK       Configured default timezone "Europe/Warsaw" must be supported by your installation of PHP
 OK       json_encode() must be available
 OK       session_start() must be available
 OK       ctype_alpha() must be available
 OK       token_get_all() must be available
 OK       simplexml_import_dom() must be available
 OK       detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PCRE extension must be available

** Optional recommendations **

 OK       Requirements file should be up-to-date
 OK       You should use at least PHP 5.3.4 due to PHP bug #52083 in earlier versions
 OK       When using annotations you should have at least PHP 5.3.8 due to PHP bug #55156
 OK       You should not use PHP 5.4.0 due to the PHP bug #61453
 OK       When using the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component, you should have at least PHP 5.4.11 due to PHP bug #63379 (as a workaround, you can also set invalidate_session to false in the security logout handler configuration)
 OK       You should use PHP 5.3.18+ or PHP 5.4.8+ to always get nice error messages for fatal errors in the development environment due to PHP bug #61767/#60909
 OK       PCRE extension should be at least version 8.0 (8.32 installed)
 OK       PHP-XML module should be installed
 OK       mb_strlen() should be available
 OK       iconv() should be available
 OK       utf8_decode() should be available
 WARNING  posix_isatty() should be available
          Install and enable the php_posix extension (used to colorize the CLI output).

 OK       intl extension should be available
 OK       intl extension should be correctly configured
 OK       intl ICU version should be at least 4+
 WARNING  a PHP accelerator should be installed
          Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).

 WARNING  short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini
          Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.

 OK       magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       register_globals should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini
 OK       PDO should be installed
 OK       PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: mysql, pgsql, sqlite)
```

Comment: run `php app/check.php` on your production server please and report back the result please. The server might lack a necessary php extension.

Comment: @nifr question updated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it's the issue (and possible solutions):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3120

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11056

Comment: The top link is broken and the answer is needlessly buried in the 2nd link.  In the future, it's a good idea to quote the links instead of only providing the source for these reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the top Google result for this error I'll just paste the dirty quick fix here to get you going more easily.

Note: In nearly every case **you shouldn't modify any vendor files like this.** However, if you have some dependency problem which couldn't be solved for some reason here's the trick for you.

This is a Doctrine error, so you should modify the Doctrine ORM bundle a bit.

Add your `PHP_VERSION_ID` to the `newInstance()` function in

```
/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
```

The final result looks like this for me:

```
public function newInstance()
{
    // echo PHP_VERSION_ID; die();  // Uncomment this, in case you don't know your PHP_VERSION_ID
    if ($this->_prototype === null) {
        if (PHP_VERSION_ID === 50429 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50513 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50603 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 70009) { // This is the tricky line
            $this->_prototype = $this->reflClass->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        } else {
            $this->_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name));
        }
    }

    return clone $this->_prototype;
}
```

*The original solution can be found here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11056*

Answer (score 1):

For those still coming across this issue, updating the doctrine/orm dependency worked.

My new doctrine dependency line in composer.json:
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.5",

Then I updated composer as per usual from the command line: php composer.phar update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by updating **"doctrine/orm"** package in Composer.json to **"~2.4"** version and then running:

***composer update doctrine/orm***
from the command line. This should only update the concerned package. After this refreshing the webpage and/or logging in again and the error was gone.

Hope this helps.